# .htaccess rewrite /folder/subfolder to /folder/?subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to do this in my .htaccess? I've tried a few solutions but couldn't get it working...

```js
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/$1\ -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /folder/\?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\ -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /\?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you post complete example input and output URLs, with detail regarding what the user's browser sends, what is processed internally by Apache, and what URL results in the browser address bar?

Comment: Ideally, I want it to do this:

Input: http://domain.com/user/home
Output: http://domain.com/user/?home

I have a single-page web app that runs in the /user/ directory and if the page is refreshed on domain.com/user/home, for example, it breaks the app.

This works, but it's not dynamic:
Redirect 301 /user/home http://localhost:8888/user/?home

Answer (score 0):

The space right before your `-f` flag should not be escaped.

Change your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /folder/?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?$1 [L]
```